# I'm looking for a manga about a girl who can smell when people are sexually aroused

Tags: para-paru

I just remember reading it along time ago. I think it was something like, she wakes up one day and goes to school, where she realizes some people smell funny. I think later some dude tells her she can smell when the people around her are sexually aroused. I know it sounds really weird for me to be searching for this... It's not that I want to read it thatt much, but I just remembered reading it and it's bothering me since I can't seem to find it...

Comment: Is this a one-shot or a series? Is it hentai (explit)? Is is shoujo or shounen? A long time ago is how many years ago? Even a ballpark estimate would help.

Answer (score 8):

I'm pretty sure it's [**Para Paru**](https://www.mangaupdates.com/series.html?id=4542) :)

It is a shoujo manga about a girl who wakes up one day finding herself being able to smell certain scents from the people around her. She also hears a strange voice inside her head. Later with the help of a friend, she finds out that an alien got inside and is now living in her head, and it is the one responsible for giving her the enhanced ability of smell. The certain scents are explained and analysed to be associated to sexual arousal and physical attraction, as well as dishonesty and nervousness, etc.

There are other people in the same school who receive similar abilities in taste, touch and hearing. The manga is ongoing and touches on sensitive and mature matters such as rape and pregnancy.

Comment: Welcome to Anime and Manga. can you expand on your answer by including a plot synopsis and/or how it matches to what the OP is asking, particularly clearing up as to why you say *"I'm pretty sure"*

Comment: Thank you for the advice. Will be adding clarification in a minute.

Comment: Welcome to Anime and Manga. This is a pretty good answer. +1

Comment: "sexual arousal" is understandable but what is "pre-sexual arousal"? Where can I ask this question? ecchi.stackexchange.com? lol.

Comment: "Pre-sexual arousal" may not be the exact term in the scanlation since I read it a while ago but basically it refers to the sexual attraction and excitement aka "I found my mating partner" lol. I would suggest you check out the manga for more info. It's a "pretty good" read considering the unique characters and less conventional approaches to common issues like school romances and friendships. The subjects being dealt with are complicated and sensitive, though, so it's definitely more "mature" and food for thought than it seems. Thanks for the +1, I hope this helps :)